# Help Qt Widgets for creating Accessories Bar on my device

Tags: qt, qwidget

For a handheld device I want to put a vertical Bar which will contain widgets that show the battery status of device, network connectivity status, Date and Time etc. For this Bar I have chosen a GroupBox and for the widgets inside that (lets say batter status) I am planning to use QPushButton. Is it correct I am doing or there is some special widgets for this purpose?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would work, but is it the best answer? That really depends on you UI design.  Qt's widgets are extremely flexible and there are many ways to do any one function.  Couple of points -

- If you don't need header over area, then you don't need group box, then you can use a plain widget or a frame as a container.
- Many objects can display graphics, so pick them for underlying functionality and make code simpler.
- All widgets can be highly customized to fit your specific needs.

Hope this helps.